# Expressing function involving Laguerre polynomial as summation of other Laguerre polynomials

Tags: polynomials, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, orthogonal-polynomials

I'm interested in expressing the function:

$x\mathcal{L}_N^m (x^2 +y^2)$

in the form

$\sum_{N_i}\sum_{m_i} c_{N_i}^{m_i}\mathcal{L}_{N_i}^{m_i} (x^2 +y^2)$

where $c_{N_i}^{m_i}$ is a constant independent of $x,y$. Most of the identities I've looked up make it easy to do this for a function that looks more like

$f(x^2 +y^2)\mathcal{L}_N^m (x^2 +y^2)$

but this case is a little different. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think it will help if you explain the context - why do you need this?

Comment: The Laguerre polynomials are part of wavefunctions of a quantum system I'm working on. Applying certain operators on these wavefunctions yields functions as the one seen above. I'm interested in re-expressing this as a sum of Laguerre polynomials.

Comment: I still don't see why you need to make you expression more complicated. If you go to cylindrical coordinates, you have $$L_N^m (r^2) \cdot r \cos \phi$$ In other words, you have explicit angle dependence. How can you expand the function so it only depends on $r$?